# View has changed when a TableView cell is selected for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I create a custom table view cell using autolayout as this picture below
[image]

When the app launch, every thing be fine. but when i scroll tableview or select a view, cell's layout will be changed.
Whats happen?

code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];
[cell.textLabel setText: textToSHow];

cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];

CGSize fitSize = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
return fitSize.height;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
TableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];
[cell.textLabel setText:textToSHow];
return  cell;
}
```

run app:

[image]

when a cell is selected:

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you calculating the row's `height` when everything is set with autolayout?

Comment: table view have a datasource named: heightforrow
so i need to calculate row's height by myself.

Comment: That's not a required method... You either use that or autolayout... if you want to go with the code I think you can remove your constraints.

Comment: i dont think you can success by this way, can you provide fully source code that can run correct?

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 8+ solution (using autolayout):**

Add this to your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

**And** remove the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change some codes in your existing implementation. Try this by replacing your existing code.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize fitSize = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return fitSize.height;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    [cell.textLabel setText:textToSHow];
    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: thank for your help. but i had the same problem when scroll the table view

Comment: look the heightForRowAtIndexPath will be called when you scroll the table view. probably the method you are using to determine the height is not correct. try to calculate height of text according to width through calculations. This is the main cause of your problem.